# Отличия определений функции с __attribute__ в C

Tags: c, атрибуты

Есть ли разница между следующими вариантами?

```
static inline void func(void) __attribute__((always_inline));
static inline void func(void)
{
    ...
}
```

и

```
static inline void func(void) __attribute__((always_inline))
{
    ...
}
```

Если нет, почему в некоторых случаях используется первый вариант? Или это сделано ради "красоты"?

Comment: *"почему в некоторых случаях используется первый вариант?"* - он используется во всех случаях, так как атрибуты не разрешены для определения функций и второй вариант не будет собираться.

Comment: В таком случае все собирается
static inline void __attribute__((always_inline)) func(void)
{
    ...
}

Comment: атрибут `always_inline` тут не причём. Предварительное объявление иногда требуется, если эта функция всем нужна и она сама ещё выполняет ещё не задекларированные функции.